# Log(2 ** 62,2).is_integer() is returning false . Any ideas why?

Tags: python, python-2.7

i am trying to print

```
>>> math.log(2 ** 62,2).is_integer()
```

which returns

```
False
```

Similarly,

```
>>> math.log(2**62,2).is_integer()
False
>>> math.log(2**26,2).is_integer()
True
>>> math.log(2**28,2).is_integer()
True
>>> math.log(2**31,2).is_integer()
False
>>> math.log(2**32,2).is_integer()
True
>>> math.log(2**33,2).is_integer()
True
>>> math.log(2**31,2).is_integer()
False
>>> math.log(2**30,2).is_integer()
True
>>> math.log(2**63,2).is_integer()
True
>>> math.log(2**64,2).is_integer()
True
>>> math.log(2**62,2).is_integer()
False
```

The results are very vague, varying differently for various integers.

Any ideas why?

**EDIT**

Sylvain mentioned here that

```
>>> math.log(2**62,2)
```

returns

```
62.00000000000001
```

why is that so? Please if anyone could explain this?

FYI -> for many numbers in range(100) it does returns proper integers as shown below

```
>>> for i in range(100):
        print 'math.log(2**'+str(i)+',2)' + ' --> ' + str(float(math.log(2**i,2))) + ' Is Integer? --> ' + str(math.log(2**i,2).is_integer())

math.log(2**0,2) --> 0.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**1,2) --> 1.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**2,2) --> 2.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**3,2) --> 3.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**4,2) --> 4.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**5,2) --> 5.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**6,2) --> 6.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**7,2) --> 7.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**8,2) --> 8.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**9,2) --> 9.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**10,2) --> 10.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**11,2) --> 11.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**12,2) --> 12.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**13,2) --> 13.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**14,2) --> 14.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**15,2) --> 15.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**16,2) --> 16.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**17,2) --> 17.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**18,2) --> 18.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**19,2) --> 19.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**20,2) --> 20.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**21,2) --> 21.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**22,2) --> 22.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**23,2) --> 23.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**24,2) --> 24.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**25,2) --> 25.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**26,2) --> 26.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**27,2) --> 27.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**28,2) --> 28.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**29,2) --> 29.0 Is Integer? --> False
math.log(2**30,2) --> 30.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**31,2) --> 31.0 Is Integer? --> False
math.log(2**32,2) --> 32.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**33,2) --> 33.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**34,2) --> 34.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**35,2) --> 35.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**36,2) --> 36.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**37,2) --> 37.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**38,2) --> 38.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**39,2) --> 39.0 Is Integer? --> False
math.log(2**40,2) --> 40.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**41,2) --> 41.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**42,2) --> 42.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**43,2) --> 43.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**44,2) --> 44.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**45,2) --> 45.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**46,2) --> 46.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**47,2) --> 47.0 Is Integer? --> False
math.log(2**48,2) --> 48.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**49,2) --> 49.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**50,2) --> 50.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**51,2) --> 51.0 Is Integer? --> False
math.log(2**52,2) --> 52.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**53,2) --> 53.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**54,2) --> 54.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**55,2) --> 55.0 Is Integer? --> False
math.log(2**56,2) --> 56.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**57,2) --> 57.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**58,2) --> 58.0 Is Integer? --> False
math.log(2**59,2) --> 59.0 Is Integer? --> False
math.log(2**60,2) --> 60.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**61,2) --> 61.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**62,2) --> 62.0 Is Integer? --> False
math.log(2**63,2) --> 63.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**64,2) --> 64.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**65,2) --> 65.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**66,2) --> 66.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**67,2) --> 67.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**68,2) --> 68.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**69,2) --> 69.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**70,2) --> 70.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**71,2) --> 71.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**72,2) --> 72.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**73,2) --> 73.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**74,2) --> 74.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**75,2) --> 75.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**76,2) --> 76.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**77,2) --> 77.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**78,2) --> 78.0 Is Integer? --> False
math.log(2**79,2) --> 79.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**80,2) --> 80.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**81,2) --> 81.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**82,2) --> 82.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**83,2) --> 83.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**84,2) --> 84.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**85,2) --> 85.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**86,2) --> 86.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**87,2) --> 87.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**88,2) --> 88.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**89,2) --> 89.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**90,2) --> 90.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**91,2) --> 91.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**92,2) --> 92.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**93,2) --> 93.0 Is Integer? --> False
math.log(2**94,2) --> 94.0 Is Integer? --> False
math.log(2**95,2) --> 95.0 Is Integer? --> False
math.log(2**96,2) --> 96.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**97,2) --> 97.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**98,2) --> 98.0 Is Integer? --> True
math.log(2**99,2) --> 99.0 Is Integer? --> True
```

Comment: I don't have python 3 to test but I'd be interested to know if this is also the case when using `math.log2`

Comment: Please **don't** change your question into a totally different question. Also, regarding your update, read [this](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/02Numerics/Double/paper.pdf).

Comment: @TomFenech: `math.log2` should be significantly better behaved, and in particular should give exact results for powers of 2.  See `http://bugs.python.org/issue11888` for some of the discussion.

Comment: Tom and Mark ! tested the same code Python 3.4 and it was integer for all cases ! :)

Comment: @Prashant: Yes, it was written with that intention.  But Python's still at the mercy of the OS when it comes to the accuracy of `2.0**n` (or of `2**n` for negative `n`), so it's possible for `log2(2**n)` to give the wrong result because of inaccuracies in the power operation.

Comment: I am sorry Bartos, I dint intend to change the question but couldn't help my curiosity regarding the issue. P.S. the section 'ROUNDING ERRORS' in the article looks promising.

Comment: @Prashant Nothing wrong with being curious. If you can't satisfy your curiosity with the resources you have (and the internet) you can always ask another question. This is the preferred way, instead of mutating one post, and IIRC there is no limit to the number of question you can ask, as long as they're of decent quality.

Answer (score 4):

All results are [floats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point). [`is_integer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer) does not check if the type of the result is integer. It checks if the floating value is an integer.

Rounding errors might made `is_integer` not reliable though:

```
>>> math.log(2**26,2)
26.0
>>> math.log(2**62,2)
62.00000000000001
```

As the above operation are performed through the use of the natural logarithm, I *guess* the rounding error here is introduced by the division by `log(2)` 
(as `math.log(x,2)` is `math.log(x)/math.log(2)`).

Comment: Okay, I shud edit my question, Why is math.log(2**62,2) returning 62.00000000000001 ?

Answer (score 3):

<strike>For numbers above 2**53 the explanation is that double precision (64-bit) floating point numbers cannot represent integers bigger than that exactly. The logarithm function in these cases is already receiving an approximate input and of course it cannot provide exact output.</strike>

**EDIT**: powers of two can be represented exactly... the problem is for integers that are NOT a power of two and bigger than 2**53.

That log fails doing an exact computation for 2**31 is indeed somewhat surprising given that apparently most common hardware for PC today has instructions for computing logarithms in base 2 in the floating point unit.

Python code is however written in C and the C library doesn't provide a logarithm in base 2 library function in all build environments Python supports. This means that all computations are done passing from natural logarithm and a change of base; this explains inaccuracies even with small values like 2**31. For the generic `math.log` function there's no special handling for the case base is 2 even if the compiler provides support for it.

Python 3 `math` module contains however a `log2` function and the code for computing the logarithm in base 2 uses a `log2` primitive if this is present on the platform. Indeed in Linux `math.log2(2**31)` is exact, while `math.log(2**31, 2)` is not. <strike>I've read somewhere that Microsoft C++ math library doesn't implement `log2` and thus I don't expect it to be exact in Python 3 implementation running in Windows (Python code is compiled with Visual C++).</strike>

**EDIT**: seems this is not true any more or was never true. `math.log2` is accurate even on Windows builds of Python 3.

Comment: FWIW, the first "failure" is at `math.log(2**29,2)`

Comment: I think you might be correct but then again there is 29!

Comment: @SylvainLeroux: 2*31 is still clearly exactly computable by the hardware without problems, and it's the first "small enough" value in the list that was in the question. Of course if you do a base change even 2**3 is going to be "risky"... it may end up rounded to the integer or not.

Comment: Small comment: powers of 2 larger than 2**53 **can** be represented exactly by floats, it is most other large integers that cannot be represented exactly. But you are right that `log(x, base)` is calculated as `log(x) / log(base)`, see [the source code](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Modules/mathmodule.c#L806) for `math.log`. But where is the special case code for log2?

Comment: @6502 , i ran it on both platforms, Linux n Windows, python 3.4 gives satisfactory results for all numbers in range(-1000,1000)

Comment: @BasSwinckels: whoops you're right... I'll fix that part. For log2 implementation in Python3 look for `mathmodule.c` (in my quite old checkout is at line 592) and see the `#ifdef HAVE_LOG2` part.

Comment: @Prashant _"python 3.4 gives satisfactory results for all numbers in range(-1000,1000)"_ Could you confirm that? On my Python 3.4.1 / Linux / amd64, `math.log(2**31,2)` evaluates to `31.000000000000004`. `log2` seems to behave correctly though.

Comment: it gives the same results on python3.4 for me also

Comment: @SylvainLeroux: I think s/he is talking about `math.log2(2**31)` in Python 3

Comment: @Prashant: then may be what I've heard about MS compilers is not valid any more... or may be there is some inline assembly for the windows build. I'm trying to update my quite outdated sandbox with the source but it's taking **ages**...

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I m talking about math.log2(2**31) and yes i have confirmed it.